# AppleScript unable to use System Events when ran using URL protocol

Tags: applescript, url-scheme, custom-url-protocol

I have an AppleScript file with following codes, that suppose to do three things -

1. Read from URL
2. Write the value to some place as text file
3. Activate an application if it's already running

Here's the code that I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
on open location this_URL
    set userHomePath to POSIX path of (path to home folder)
    set argFile to userHomePath & "Downloads/uriNotifier.txt"
    do shell script "echo  " & quoted form of this_URL & " >  " & quoted form of argFile
end open location

set processIsRunning to true
tell application "System Events"
    set runningProcesses to processes whose bundle identifier is "my.App.ID"
end tell
if runningProcesses is {} then set processIsRunning to false
if processIsRunning is true then
    do shell script "open -b \"my.App.ID\""
end if
```

I export the file as *Application*, and modified its `Info.plist` file to enable URL protocol:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.ScriptEditor.id.SendToMyApplication</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.apple.ScriptEditor.id.SendToMyApplication</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>sendtomyapplication</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>NSAppleEventsUsageDescription</key>
<string>Sending for my application.</string>
```

Now when I ran the protocol on a browser using `sendtomyapplication://someValue` it does following things:

1. It triggers the application I exported with AppleScript successfully
2. It writes the URL value to a text file under `Users/$user/Downloads/uriNotifier.txt`
3. It fails to activate the application with ID `my.App.ID`

However, if I ran the AppleScript-application by double-click, or from Terminal, it successfully able to activate the application with ID `my.App.ID`.

Can someone please point me what I'm doing wrong that when it is running from URL, the targeted application is not activating (?) Thanks!

Comment: Why not simply `if application "MyApp" is running then activate application "MyApp"` where `MyApp` is the name of the application (unlike the bundle identifier)? Any application even without an AppleScript dictionary responds to `is running` and `activate`

Comment: Note that while the (implied) `run` handler is getting executed when running the application, only the `open location` handler gets called for the URL.